# Using "for good."

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction

*After the final blow, he was knocked out for good.*

Is ***for good*** used correctly in this sentence?

Comment: If you mean he died after that, then yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"For good" in this context idiomatically means indefinitely, or forever. If you are talking about someone being knocked *unconscious*, adding "for good" would imply that they never wake up.